# When should I be using async/await and when should I be using callbacks [js]?

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback

My API calls have typically been formatted in the callback pattern similar to this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/announcements')
  .then((res) => res)
  .catch((err) => err)
```

However, I've recently come across async/await and the following function appears to do the same but more succintly.

```
const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/announcements');
return response
```

When should I be using the callback pattern and when should I be using async/await?

Comment: I’m not a pro but I'd say using `.then()` is more useful for when you just wanna call a function on a promise, and `async/await` is good when you want to store the resolved promise.

Comment: I think whatever suggestions people come up with, they'll somehow fall between being subjective and objective. Here is mine: Use `async/await` if possible, the promise API if necessary. The reason being that `async/await` uses/requires less boilerplate code and is more expressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just the same thing in 2 different syntaxes and choosing between them is just personal preferences. For me, I would always go for `async/await` instead of `.then()` and `.catch()` because:

1. **Easier to implement complex async logics**: With `.then()`, the rest of the program, if you want it to run after the task is completed, has to lie in the `.then()` block. If you need to return a promise again, you need to use chained `.then()`. For more complex cases (multiple promises before resolving, promises loop, etc.), the solutions become significantly harder to implement. There are multiple cases I have to rewrite all my code in `async/await`.
2. **Familiar and cross-language syntax**: With `async/await` the code is written just like any normal code. I can use loops, multiple promises, and the normal 'return' to return the awaited value with ease. `.catch` does not typically exist in other languages, but rather a `try catch` block making it easier to understand for people from other languages.

Comment: After examination, it seems that async/await is syntactical sugar that is functionally the same as .then() / .catch() with the exception that one returns a promise object, the other is raw data.